# JPanels TextFields GBC

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I dont understand why my textfields are coming up as slits instead of the size given ? Is there something I'm missing , or what I'm thinking is the problem is the constraints I put are too small ?Thanks in Advance !

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class addEntry 
{

public void addEntryFrame()
{
    JFrame entryFrame = new JFrame("Passafe");
    entryFrame.setSize(500,500);
    entryFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel topHeader = new JLabel("Add New Entry: ");

    topHeader.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.BOLD, 24));
    topPanel.add(topHeader);

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(15,15,15,15);
    JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: ");
    JLabel username = new JLabel("Username: ");
    JLabel password = new JLabel("Password: ");
    JLabel description = new JLabel("Description: ");
    JTextField nametf = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField usernametf = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField passwordtf = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField descriptiontf = new JTextField(50);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    centerPanel.add(name, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    centerPanel.add(nametf, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    centerPanel.add(username, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    centerPanel.add(usernametf, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    centerPanel.add(password, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    centerPanel.add(passwordtf, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    centerPanel.add(description, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    centerPanel.add(descriptiontf, gbc);

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton saveEntryButton = new JButton("SAVE");
    bottomPanel.add(saveEntryButton);

    entryFrame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    entryFrame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    entryFrame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    entryFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `entryFrame.setSize(500, 500);` instead of that use `entryFrame.pack();` at the end of `addEntryFrame()` method.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ! will click the green check in 8 minutes ! lol